# SwiftUI - How to write parent Document ID to child document field value

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Using SwiftUI and Cloud Firestore, I am looking to create a new child document that has 3 fields:

```
studentFirstName <- entered into textfield
studentLastName <- entered into textfield
schoolID <- This will be the document ID of the parent document
```

I'm using textfields to enter the studentFirstName and studentLastName, and that is working great.  I can get the Document ID of the parent, but trying to figure out how when I press the "Save" button, to have it write the 2 values from the textfields (this is already working as desired) as well as create the schoolID field and populate it with the Document ID value.

Does anyone have a quick and easy solution for this?  I can add my code in, but it's pretty straight forward.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**View code for reference:**

```
struct StudentListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var schoolViewModel = SchoolViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var studentViewModel = StudentViewModel()
    
    let school: School
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(studentViewModel.student) { i in
                    if school.schoolName == i.schoolName {
                        NavigationLink {
                            StudentDetalView(student: i)
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text(i.studentName)
                                Text(", ")
                                Text(i.id!)
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationTitle(school.schoolName)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.studentViewModel.fetchStudentData()
            }
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $studentViewModel.newStudent.studentFirstName)
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $studentViewModel.newStudent.studentLastName)
                    
                } header: {
                    Text("Add New Student")
                }
            }
            Button {
                studentViewModel.addStudentData(documentId: self.school.id!)
            } label: {
                Text("Save").font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addStudentData method I would do something like this:

```
func addStudentData(dict: [String: Any]) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let pathToCreateDocument = db.collection("students") // Set this to whatever your path is  
    pathToCreateDocument.document().setData(dict)
}
```

Then in your SwiftUI 'Save' Button

```
Button {
    let dict = ["studentFirstName": studentViewModel.newStudent.studentFirstName,
           "studentLastName":studentViewModel.newStudent.studentLastName,
           "schoolId":self.school.id!] // highly suggest unwrapping your optionals with like an if let or guard statement rather than force unwrapping them

    studentViewModel.addStudentData(dict: dict)
} label: {
    Text("Save")
        .font(.title)
}
```